# Cannot redirect with window.location.href inside a function

Tags: javascript

I'm calling a specific function in a software that help to me send data to javascript file. I need to put the data in a txt file. So this is how I proceeded :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>test_diagram</title>
    <script src="raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="sequence-diagram-min.js"></script>
    <div id="diagram"></div>
        <script>
            function fromSoftToWeb(iParam1, iParam2){
                alert("FromSoftToWeb ---- P1: " + iParam1 + " - P2: " + iParam2);
                try {
                    window.location.href = 'http://localhost/scripts/Version_reconnaissance_extension/TEST.php';
               }
                catch(err) {
                    alert(err);
                }
            };
        </script>

</head>
<body>  
</body>
```

window.location.href works only when there is no function. There is also no error when I do a try catch ..Maybe it's the software ? I don't think so because it calls a script that is outside the software.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: You have not closed try block

Comment: Use full url (including protocol like http://)

Comment: I did now but still the problem no error and no redirection even with absolute href

Comment: And no error (alert) was shown?

Comment: you know you have to call the function right? aside, that <div> in the <head> ain't right...

Comment: The function is called from a UI Web from a software. The first alert works.

Answer (score 1):

Please close your try-block. It will then do the alert from first line and after you close the alert it will redirect. When you still have redirect Problems you could try an absolute href.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I closed the try-block and I still no error but no redirection even with absolute href. It only works without a function

Comment: I tested it and it works within the function. how do you call the fucntion and where?

Comment: I call the function from a software from a play button after inserting the script's link with localhost. It reach my function because the first alert works but it doesn't redirect.